# how can I convert "[1,2,3]" string to list [1,2,3]?

Tags: python-2.7

I have string like `"[1,2,3]"`. Now I am trying convert this string to a list. That list should contain `[1,2,3]`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_val](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

**Example:**

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is doing what exactly I want.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do that is to simply use JSON, which happens to have the same encoding:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[1,2,3]')
[1,2,3]
>>> type(json.loads('[1,2,3]'))
<type 'list'>
>>> type(json.loads('[1,2,3]')[0])
<type 'int'>
```